# translate3d() causes clipping in Safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit, translate3d

I have a web app that I am developing that relies heavily on absolute positioning, CSS transforms, and CSS transitions.

My markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="background" ></div>
    <div class="foreground" >
        <div class="image" ></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

My CSS

```
.wrapper{
    -webkit-perspective: 1600;
    -webkit-perspective-origin-y: 30%;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

.background{
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8321/8038059897_403c567211.jpg");
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    bottom: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
}

.foreground{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(25deg);
}

.foreground .image{
    background-image: url("http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6139/6198476123_754eaa1920_m.jpg");
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,10px,0px);
}
```

You can see it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/KjG3f/24/

If you look at the example in Safari (both desktop and iOS), you'll see that the foreground image is clipped by the background.  In Chrome, however, it seems to work correctly.

Removing the translate3d() from the background seems to cause rendering to work, but I require the translate3d() to be there for animation purposes.

Preemptive thanks for help.
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider this a bug in Chrome, and indeed there are two issues open regarding it (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116710 and http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102673). Firefox exhibits the same behavior.

The Safari way of doing it makes sense...when you rotate the foreground image in a 3D space, it *should* clip through the image behind it, as they're on the same plane. If you change the translate3d Z-value on either the foreground or background elements, you can move them forward or backwards to where they don't intersect.

Cross-browser support for 3D transforms is unfortunately still pretty weak, good luck!

Comment: A valid point.  I guess clipping _should_ be happening.  Hmm.  I guess my real question then becomes, "How do I position an item using translate3d() such that it doesn't clip?"  But your answer is correct and does a great job of answering the original question. Thanks!

Comment: I think your best bet to positioning them in a way that they don't clip is to change the Z value in the translate3d(x,y,z). You can push the background farther back by adjusting the Z value until it no longer clips in Safari. To accomodate the change in size as it moves backwards you can add a scale() to make it appear larger. I haven't played with this, but I think you should be able to make it look the same in both browsers.