# CSS3 Transistion not worked properly in safari 3.1.7

Tags: html, css

I have a page element that is CSS3, I want transit image from left to right with fadeout.

It works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, IE, OP, but not in Safari 5.1.7 windows.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/5a1q8sen/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<li class="product">
     <div class="image"><img src="http://elektronika.techtestbox.com/images/product.png"></div>
     <span>Products</span>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.product .image img
{
  animation:fadeOutRight 5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeOutRight 5s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: fadeOutRight 5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: fadeOutRight 5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOutRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

**[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/5a1q8sen/2/)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [translate3d() causes clipping in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698206/translate3d-causes-clipping-in-safari)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 0px);
            transform: translate(100px, 0px);
  }
}
```

translate3d some problem for windows safari..

Demo Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/5a1q8sen/2/

Comment: but annoys from other browsers.